# Slick2D UnicodeFont drawstring gets rid of rest of screen

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl, slick2d

I can't determine any possible reason as to why using `UnicodeFont.drawString()` causes anything else rendered to the screen in an LWJGL application to disappear. In my case, the program should draw a triangle and some text, just to test things out, but what instead happens is that the triangle displays for a single frame before disappearing leaving only the text to be displayed. The triangle appears as normal if the `drawString()` call is removed.

I set up the font as follows:

```
        UnicodeFont font = new UnicodeFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 24));
        font.getEffects().add(new ColorEffect(java.awt.Color.WHITE));
        font.addAsciiGlyphs();
        try {
            font.loadGlyphs();
        } catch (SlickException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Then call this in the render loop:

```
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

        glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fbid);
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fbid2);
        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 4);
        font.drawString(100, 300, "Test");

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        DisplayManager.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like my problem stemmed from a mess-up with enabling/disabling textures. I resolved it by adding the following to the beginning of my render loop:

```
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

and adding this before the call to `drawString(...)`:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA):
```